# my jquery function showing only first image even when clicking other image i want the correct image to be displayed on clicking that image

Tags: php, jquery, html

How to get the correct image instead of getting the first image using jquery, whats wrong with the code below, can anyone help me out. it is also alerting undefined in alert box

This is My php page which is recieving multiple images file from the database using php mysql

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="food_test.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="showImages">
        </div>
```

This pice of code below loops through the images from the database

```
<?php
            for($i = 0; $i < $dbImg->count(); $i++){
                $imgId = $dbImg->results()[$i]->gal_img_id;
                $imgName = $dbImg->results()[$i]->gal_img_name;

                echo "<a id='imgLink' href='image_gallery.php'>";
                echo "<img id='galleryImage' width='100px' height='100px' 
                src='../images/pages/gallery/". $imgName . "'></img>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' id='" . $imgId . "' name='gal_img_id' 
                value='" . $imgName . "'></input>";
                echo $imgName;
                echo "</a>";
            }

            ?>
```

Here is my jquery code which is displaying only first image whenever i click any image.

```
        $("a#imgLink img#galleryImage").each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){                   
                $("#showImages").html($("input[name='gal_img_id']").val());             
                alert($("input[name='gal_img_id']").val());                 
            });
        }); 
    </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to single quotes.

```
$("#showImages").html($("input[name=gal_img_id]").val());             
alert($("input[name=gal_img_id]").val());
```

Try this. I had a error like this then i removed quotes from the `input[name=example]` and it worked.